# On Android, AWSMobileClient.showSignIn callback is not called when user cancels

Tags: android, aws-sdk, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I'm using Amazon's included Sign In UI, which loads and displays prefectly, but when the user hits the backpress and returns to the calling activity, the callback is not called either for success or error, AND subsequent calls to showSignIn have no effect -- no log statements or UI. Also, of course, the userstate listener is not called.

Here is the calling code and callbacks from the action button of my main activity:

```
fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
    Log.d("MainActivity", "fab click")

    AWSMobileClient.getInstance().apply {

        showSignIn(
            this@MainActivity,
            SignInUIOptions.builder().apply {canCancel(true) }.build(),
            object: Callback<UserStateDetails> {
                override fun onResult(result: UserStateDetails?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signin success")
                }

                override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signin failed")
                }
            })

    }
}
```

Here is the log covering from onStart, the first click and UI display, cancel, and two subsequent clicks:

```
2019-03-21 10:30:32.379 D/MainActivity: onStart
2019-03-21 10:30:32.454 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Detected Android API Level = 25
2019-03-21 10:30:32.454 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Using keyAlias = com.amazonaws.mobile.client.aesKeyStoreAlias
2019-03-21 10:30:32.527 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Creating the AWSKeyValueStore with key for sharedPreferences = com.amazonaws.mobile.client
2019-03-21 10:30:32.542 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Detected Android API Level = 25
2019-03-21 10:30:32.546 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Using keyAlias = com.amazonaws.android.auth.aesKeyStoreAlias
2019-03-21 10:30:32.571 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Creating the AWSKeyValueStore with key for sharedPreferences = com.amazonaws.android.auth
2019-03-21 10:30:32.571 D/AWSMobileClient: Using the SignInProviderConfig from `awsconfiguration.json`.
2019-03-21 10:30:32.576 D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2019-03-21 10:30:32.647 D/AppSyncOfflineMutationManager: Thread:[319]: Internet CONNECTED.
2019-03-21 10:30:32.707 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Detected Android API Level = 25
2019-03-21 10:30:32.707 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Using keyAlias = com.amazonaws.android.auth.aesKeyStoreAlias
2019-03-21 10:30:32.711 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-03-21 10:30:32.711 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-03-21 10:30:32.711 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-03-21 10:30:32.711 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-03-21 10:30:32.719 D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9e205780: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2019-03-21 10:30:32.720 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e205780: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9c0fe150)
2019-03-21 10:30:32.721 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
2019-03-21 10:30:32.721 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
2019-03-21 10:30:32.721 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Creating the AWSKeyValueStore with key for sharedPreferences = com.amazonaws.android.auth
2019-03-21 10:30:32.722 D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Loading credentials from SharedPreferences
2019-03-21 10:30:32.722 D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: No valid credentials found in SharedPreferences
2019-03-21 10:30:32.775 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Detected Android API Level = 25
2019-03-21 10:30:32.775 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Using keyAlias = CognitoIdentityProviderCache.aesKeyStoreAlias
2019-03-21 10:30:32.794 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Creating the AWSKeyValueStore with key for sharedPreferences = CognitoIdentityProviderCache
2019-03-21 10:30:32.811 D/AWSMobileClient: Inspecting user state details
2019-03-21 10:30:32.811 D/UserStateCB: success
2019-03-21 10:30:32.816 I/userState: user is signed out
2019-03-21 10:30:32.954 W/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0::Mapper: getService: found null hwbinder interface
2019-03-21 10:30:33.105 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e205780: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9c0fe150)
2019-03-21 10:30:33.600 I/Choreographer: Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2019-03-21 10:30:40.870 D/MainActivity: fab click
2019-03-21 10:30:40.871 D/AWSMobileClient: Inspecting user state details
2019-03-21 10:30:40.883 D/AWSMobileClient: Retrieving the client instance for class: class com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.ui.SignInUI
2019-03-21 10:30:40.883 D/SignInUI: Initializing SignInUI.
2019-03-21 10:30:40.883 D/AWSMobileClient: Created the new client: com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.ui.SignInUI@1b9029d
2019-03-21 10:30:40.887 D/SignInUI: Initiating the SignIn flow.
2019-03-21 10:30:40.887 D/SignInUI: User is not signed-in. Presenting the SignInUI.
2019-03-21 10:30:40.887 D/SignInUI: Presenting the SignIn UI.
2019-03-21 10:30:40.888 D/CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider: Initializing Cognito User Pools
2019-03-21 10:30:40.889 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Detected Android API Level = 25
2019-03-21 10:30:40.889 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Using keyAlias = CognitoIdentityProviderCache.aesKeyStoreAlias
2019-03-21 10:30:40.898 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Creating the AWSKeyValueStore with key for sharedPreferences = CognitoIdentityProviderCache
2019-03-21 10:30:41.200 D/SignInView: Using defaults: backgroundColor = -12303292; logoResId = 2131165277
2019-03-21 10:30:41.200 D/SignInView: Background Color : -12303292
2019-03-21 10:30:41.200 D/SignInView: Logo : 2131165277
2019-03-21 10:30:41.228 D/SignInView: Trying to create an instance of UserPoolSignInView
2019-03-21 10:30:41.323 D/SignInView: Skipping creating the SignInButtons. No SignInbuttons were added to the view.
2019-03-21 10:30:41.415 I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=25KB, data=28KB
2019-03-21 10:30:41.416 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=25KB, data=28KB
2019-03-21 10:30:41.416 I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
2019-03-21 10:30:41.419 I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=25KB, data=45KB
2019-03-21 10:30:41.419 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=25KB, data=45KB
2019-03-21 10:30:41.419 I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
2019-03-21 10:30:41.422 I/zygote: JIT allocated 72KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
2019-03-21 10:30:41.422 I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
2019-03-21 10:30:41.717 I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=122KB, data=72KB
2019-03-21 10:30:41.719 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=116KB, data=51KB
2019-03-21 10:30:41.733 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e205780: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9c0fe150)
2019-03-21 10:30:41.818 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e205780: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9c0fe150)
2019-03-21 10:30:41.917 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e205780: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9c0fe150)
2019-03-21 10:30:43.752 D/MainActivity: onStart
2019-03-21 10:30:43.830 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e205780: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9c0fe150)
2019-03-21 10:30:46.439 D/MainActivity: fab click
2019-03-21 10:30:49.144 D/MainActivity: fab click
```

I've tried adding releaseSignInWait and signOut to the onStart (if AWSMobileClient has been initialized), and even re-initializing in onStart, but this doesn't make any difference.

So, how can I determine whether and when to call releaseSignInWait? Is there something else I need to do to refresh the mobile client state so the showSignIn will work again? Am I doing it all wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `authenticationActivity` you want to have an `UserStateListener` like this:

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().addUserStateListener(new UserStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUserStateChanged(UserStateDetails userStateDetails) {
                switch (userStateDetails.getUserState()){
                    case GUEST:
                        Log.i("userState", "user is in guest mode");
                        break;
                    case SIGNED_OUT:
                        //This is the case that most likely interest you
                        //showSignIn() calls the the builder for displaying the sign in form 
                        Log.i("userState", "user is signed out");
                        showSignIn();
                        break;
                    case SIGNED_IN:
                        Log.i("userState", "user is signed in");
                        break;
                    case SIGNED_OUT_USER_POOLS_TOKENS_INVALID:
                        Log.i("userState", "need to login again");
                        break;
                    case SIGNED_OUT_FEDERATED_TOKENS_INVALID:
                        Log.i("userState", "user logged in via federation, but currently needs new tokens");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.e("userState", "unsupported");
                }
            }
        });
```

(I have added every possible case but you most likely are gonna use the `SIGNED_OUT` one).

Then you can offer the logout option in whatever activity you like with a simple `AWSMobileClient.getInstance().signOut()`